# How can I generate a dictionary of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension, defaultdict

how can i create something like this

```
in the kitchen  :  {'2010-01-05': [{'activity': '...'}, {'activity':'...'}, {'activity':'...'}], '2010-01-06':[{'activity':'...'}, {'activity':'...'}] }
```

if my list looks like this?

```
my_list= [
    ['2010-01-05 12:32:05', 'in the kitchen', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-05 12:32:07', 'in the living room', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-05 12:32:08', 'in the kitchen', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-05 12:32:09', 'in the living room', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-05 12:32:10', 'in the kitchen', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-06 02:32:11', 'in the kitchen', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-05 02:32:15', 'in the living room', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-05 02:32:17', 'in the living room', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-06 02:32:20', 'in the kitchen', 'ON']]
```

i tried doing this

```
my_Dict= {}
for i, item in enumerate(my_list): 
..... # calculating for every item the info i want to put in my dict .....
 res = str(time)
 p = item[0].split()  # because i only want the date as key, not also the time
   if item[1] not in my_Dict.keys(): 
       my_Dict[item[1]] = dict()
          if item[0] not in my_Dict.keys():  # creo un altro dizionario con key la data
              my_Dict[item[1]][p[0]] = defaultdict(list)
              my_Dict[item[1]][p[0]]["activity"].append(res)
```

where "time" is pandas datetime, but the output it gives is

```
in the kitchen  :  {'2010-01-05': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'attività': ['0 days 00:00:01']}), '2010-01-06': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'attività': ['0 days 00:00:09']})}

in the living room  :  {'2010-01-05': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'attività': ['0 days 00:00:03']})}
```

not considering the other times the sensor was active

Comment: Is the 2nd element always 'in the kitchen'? If not, what should happen? Also, what is time in ```res = str(time)```?

Comment: "but the output it gives is" Okay, and **what is wrong with** this output? Please read [mre] and make sure we can copy and paste the code, including example input, and see the exact problem (including exactly how the actual output is different from the desired output). Also, try to explain, in complete English sentences, what *steps need to be taken* in order to solve the problem, and *how* you intend for the code to implement those steps. Also try reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to *check* exactly where the code goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
my_list = [
    ['2010-01-05 12:32:05', 'in the kitchen', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-05 12:32:08', 'in the kitchen', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-05 12:32:10', 'in the kitchen', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-06 02:32:11', 'in the kitchen', 'ON'],
    ['2010-01-06 02:32:20', 'in the kitchen', 'ON']
]

my_dict = {}
for datetime, location, activity in my_list:
    date, time = datetime.split()
    my_dict.setdefault(location, {})
    my_dict[location].setdefault(date, [])
    my_dict[location][date].append({"activity": activity})
```

Output (my_dict):

```
{'in the kitchen': {'2010-01-05': [{'activity': 'ON'}, {'activity': 'ON'}, {'activity': 'ON'}], '2010-01-06': [{'activity': 'ON'}, {'activity': 'ON'}]}}
```

Comment: @LabarbonaDibaggio btw, I have edited the code to a shorter one to save you some lines.